# "The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened." while installing Ubuntu Studio 12.10

Tags: package-management, software-installation, 12.10

I've used UNetBootin for install Ubuntu Studio 12.10 on my USB drive. When it boots, I choose to install Ubuntu Studio but after a step, it gave me this error:

> E:Read error - read (5: Input/output error), E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

How can I resolve?

On the computer, there isn't any file. After the install crash, it goes to the Try Of Ubuntu Studio.

Another that thing I have noticed is that I can't install any packages.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to check md5 sum of your image file?
Just make md5sum of your iso image files, and then compare it with md5sum that are available from download site, in this case go to ubuntu studio web site and find proper md5sum for your iso file. sonmetimes with torrent downloading this happens.

Comment: no. Is there any way i can do it? I'm writing from Ubuntu Studio Try, and the USB isn't mounted.

Comment: then you see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840782/how-a-download-user-checks-md5-after-file-download

Comment: I understand, got it :)

Comment: the result to md5sum /dev/sdb is "Permission Denied"; i've tried with sudo too.

Comment: don't try to make md5sum for your usb disk, but just for your iso file to make sure that it has been downloaded properly.

Comment: i don't have the iso file on the disk. It's in the usb drive, installed with unetbootin. I don't think it's a problem of the iso. I've problem with apt too.

Comment: iso file that you used with unetbootin

Comment: i haven't the iso i downloaded.

Comment: well, that's something else, I think that your downloaded file has a problem, and I wanted you to make sure that you have used a healthy file ;)

Comment: i downloaded it from ubuntu studio official site with torrent.